# Joining nodes in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

How to join nodes in SceneKit models together so that any modification of position or size of one of this node can affect to position (and, optionally, size) of others? For example, using great tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/83748/beginning-scene-kit-tutorial, I've build model of methane molecule. I need automatically change position of four hydrogen atom if I programmatically change radius of carbon atom in center of model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can group all your *atom* nodes under a common *molecule* node (that node doe snot have any geometry, just child nodes). When you move or scale the molecule, the effect will be applied on every atom.

Comment: [molecule flattenedClone]; Would flatten all the child nodes into one node. ;-)

Comment: this is not a good idea. Atoms can share the same geometry data (they all are spheres with the same tessellation parameters) which is great. By flattening the node you create a huge geometry with a gigantic number of vertices.

Comment: The number of vertices don't rise in number. FlattenedClone will make it so you can't move around individual children and stores memory for only one clone, thus using up less memory all together by reducing the number of pointers.

Comment: the number of vertices increases drastically. Because the new geometry is made of all the other geometries in the flattened node tree, and because their vertices have to be moved according to their node's transform, they can't be reused. So if a sphere has N vertices, and you flatten a node tree that has M spheres, you end up with one geometry made of N*M vertices.